# Assign variable to values from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, with a year as the first key, and dictionary as the value, with a name the key for that dictionary, and a list of tuples as the value for the inner-dictionary, like so:

```
dictionary={2009:{Adam:[(a,b,c,d),(e,f,g,h)]}
```

How can I assign variables for different values with the list of tuples?
For example, if I want:

```
var_1=a
var_2=c
var_3=g
```

How can I assign them? I've tried for loops, but seem to get stuck, and the list of tuples within the dictionary aspect is probably not helping the organization.

Comment: You want to assign them all to variables ? is theere a pattern youre expecting ?

Comment: I think I will need to use them all, so a pattern would be expected. I just used 3 variables as an example, but the dictionary has multiple keys, and even more sub-keys. I filter them by the first key, and then go from there printing certain values as I need to.